# Casting to run-time type

Tags: c#, design-patterns, abstract-class

Here is my structure :

```
Abstract Class - Action
--Abstract Class - ConfigsAction
---- ResetAction
---- SetToZeroAction
--Abstract Class - SettingsAction
---- EditLanguageAction
---- ChangeColorPrefAction
```

ManagerAccessPoint.Receive(Action action)

ManagerAccesPoint receives the action and ''sends'' it to the proper ConcreteManager.
So ManagerAccessPoint needs to Cast it either to ConfigsAction or SettingsAction
And ConfigManager/SettingsManager would then cast it to the proper action class would it be ResetAction, SetToZeroAction, EditLanguageAction or ChangeColorPrefAction.

I know i can save the action type with

```
Object.getType().name
```

as a string.
I know I can get the type back from the string with

```
Type­.GetType(string)
```

But how do I cast it back to that type  ? It could be visualized as if it was this :

```
Retrievetype derievedAction =  (RetrieveType)myAction
```

Where retrieveType is a Type variable

I found other ''similar'' question but none were giving me a working solution for my situation.

I actually need to be able to call Child's classe specific function once I received teh action at the right level, so that the behaviour is different for every child class.

Comment: It doesn't make sense - in C#, the type of each variable is fixed at compile time - be it a standard type, `dynamic` or a type parameter for generics. If you make the left-hand side of your bottom assignment `object` or `dynamic` then of course you can assign the right-hand side now - but now the cast is pointless too and so `RetrieveType` disappears completely.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you are saying.

I actually need to cast it so I can access child's class specific function.

Comment: In my experience there are three routes available in situations like this: A) switch on type and cast to actual type in the case body B) create a common set of methods at `Action` level then cast everything as that type C) abstract the factory logic in to a method that returns a `dynamic`.

Comment: I'm trying not to have a huge switch case that i need to maintain. 

Dynamic seems not so bad but it's error prone :S

I'm not quite sure to get what is option B?

Comment: I read somewhere that reflection could help me ? but I'm not quite sure how, never really used reflection before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class structure looks fine , and the concept of manager is also fine . But if you need to call a specific functionality of child class then we are losing/going away from the Abstraction concept.
Try to handle these via virtual/abstract contract methods.

For eg:

```
    class ManagerAccessPoint
    {
         public void Receive (Action action)
         {
             //where CallContractMethod is an abstract/virtual method
             //which serves as a contract and now via run time polymorphism
             //the appropriate action method will be called.
             //Each and every child class will have different behavior of this action.
             action.CallContractMethod();
         }
    }
```

Comment: You win, design wise :)

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking doesn't make sense. A cast is useful only if the type you're casting to is known statically at compile time, otherwise how would you do anything with it?

Comment: I get your point, but how could I use my object and call ''child class's specific function ? There is dynamic has someother suggested, but to I'd prefer finding a safer way and less error prone.

Comment: @Fawar, cast it to the specific type that exposes that specific function. Or, if you can, define that function in an abstract base class and override it in the derived class; this way you take advantage of polymorphism and don't need to check the actual type.

Comment: I was actually working on something similar since I replied. Might include a visitor pattern so that it doesn't have to know anything :)

Answer (score 1):

In short, you can't.  You could use the 'dynamic' object which would allow you write code as if it had been cast, but I don't think that would be appropriate here.

Instead, you could try something like:

```
class ManagerAccessPoint
{
    private ConfigManager _configManager;
    private SettingsManager _settingsManager;

    void Receive(Action action)
    {
        var configs = action as ConfigsAction;
        if (configs != null)
        {
            _configManager.Receive(configs);    
            return;
        }
        var settings = action as SettingsAction;
        if (settings != null)
        {
            _settingsManager.Receive(settings);    
            return;
        }

    }
}

class ConfigManager
{
    void Receive(ConfigsAction action)
    {
      // repeat the same pattern here
      var setToZero = action as SetToZeroAction;
      if (setToZero != null)
      {
          // we have a setToZero action!
      }
      etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll be having more than 2 manager... might be around 10 each with a set of different actions... That clearly could work and is mostly equivalent to a use switch case on a ''action'' field that would be a Type == typeof(eachActionSubClass) but it would be processing alot of casting/conditions for Null values :S